# JSON include with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

Let's say I have this code snippet

```
user = User.find(1)
user.to_json(:include => :posts)
```

What if I want to include the user's posts with a certain condition like posts that are only a week old?

Answer (score 6):

Define a new method called `week_old_posts` in the `User` model:

```
def week_old_posts
  posts.where("created_at > ?", 1.week.ago)
end
```

Then in your `to_json` call use `methods` rather than `include`:

```
user.to_json(:methods => :week_old_posts)
```

`:include` is more useful if you want to include a whole association, use methods for when you want to include parts of associations.

Comment: That would work except that it adds another level to the JSON hierarchy, any ideas on how to rectify that?