# Sending a query string to rails respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am rather new to ruby and rails development. 
for the past little while, I have been trying to figure out how I can pass params/query string to a rails respond_to block. I am focusing on the json response.

Say I have the following

```
def index
   @employees = Employee.all

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @employees }
   end
end
```

and I am looking to only get a json response containing employees who have an id that is greater than 500. What would be the best way to go about this.

I have been trying to make the json request using jQuery.ajax() and I know you can pass data to the server that is formatted to a query, but not sure how to make it work.

The above example is only hypothetical. I am only looking for a way to be able to use a query sting when wanting a json response.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139212/json-include-with-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Whatever parameters are sent with the request (in the query string) should be available in your controller (check the `params` variable).  Here's one way to get the Employees with id's at & above 500:

Replace

```
@employees = Employee.all
```

with

```
@employees = Employee.find(:all, conditions: ["id >= ?", 500])
```

Please note that you don't need to pass anything besides the format to that `respond_to` block.